# Pronunciation of "Je suis en retard."?

Tags: prononciation

The FSI French phonology course pronounces it in four syllables with retard's 'e' swallowed up. Like:

ʒə sɥi zɑ̃ʁ taʁ

More contemporary samples I've heard pronounce it in five like:

ʒə sɥi zɑ̃ ʁətaʁ

That's a pretty significant difference! What should a novice French learner like myself make of it?

Comment: The most common real life pronunciation uses two syllables: /ʃɥiɑ̃ʁtaʁ/ (*ch'uian r'tar*)

Comment: @jlliagre Good point. What's the likelihood of /ʒə sɥi/ being directly followed by /ɑ̃ʁtaʁ/ ? ;)

Comment: @LukeSawczak That would probably be the second most common case, followed by the formal ones with a liaison.

Comment: @jlliagre Interesting. If *en retard* behaves like that without the rest of the sentence showing rapid speech, maybe the effect does have to do with acting like a single phonological unit instead of two words.

Comment: It's not a significant difference.  You're making a mountain of a molehill.  A parisian in a hurry or a pompous professor will naturally fall into one or the other, take your pick. You'd do best to focus on pronouncing the 'en' properly and not slipping in the final 'd', if you really want to obsess.

Comment: @GeorgeM Your comment reminds me of [this](https://xkcd.com/386/).

Comment: @Jaguar0616 :-)  I was thinking more of this: https://xkcd.com/356/

Comment: Let me also point out that you're examining half the problem..  "r'tard' usually is paired with 'chuis' rather than 'je suis'..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the question of the unstressed syllable in the middle of *en retard* dropping out. This can indeed be done in rapid speech.

For a word like *appeler*, you can expect even [a dictionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/appeler#Verbe) to mention the fact that the middle syllable can drop out. In fact, it's normal. But for *[retard](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_retard)*, if viewed in isolation, you couldn't do so, because [ʁt] is not a valid onset.

However, in very fluid speech, sequences like this often break phonological barriers like word edges. That is, the  [ʁ] is happy to become the coda of a previous open syllable even if it's in another word, and then the unstressed syllable will indeed drop out. It helps that *en retard* is such a common collocation that an unconscious parsing as one lexical item is plausible, but even in a phrase like *se retrouve par terre* the first three syllables could be realized as two: *[se r'trouve par terre](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Thi6zfy6h2bz6s7b76wnfslaizy?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics)* [səʁ tʁuv ...].

For *en retard*, you can expect to hear the two-syllable pronunciation in quick, familiar speech but all three syllables everywhere else. Here's an example with [three](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0PcsyeGgVk) and here's an example with [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWKdOeJrwrE).

As a learner, you can never go wrong with three syllables here. (Whereas for single words like *appeler*, pronouncing all three might seem like you're spelling it out for someone hard of hearing. That's my impression as a non-native speaker, anyhow, so I invite correction if needed!)